# Visual studio backward compatibility

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome

I saw on chrome project where they said we can use VS08 to build the project code but not VS10. What exactly is the issue with the backward compatibility of VS? Is there any way to solve it without installing the previous version?

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows look under "Build Environment" section. "Visual Studio 2010 doesn't yet work" Thats what they say!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project files are of different formats and contain different project/solution specific meta-data.

VS2010 will automatically convert VS2008 projects.

---

It appears from the page, that both VS 2005 and VS 2008 require a bunch of hotfixes to be installed.

This suggests that there are certain bugs in the plain vanilla version that the hotfixes address, which have probably not been addressed in VS 2010 yet. If this is the case, and the fixed are *required* for a successful compilation, you have your explanation.

Comment: chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows look under "Build Environment" section. "Visual Studio 2010 doesn't yet work" Thats what they say!!

Comment: @mihsathe - I saw that. Unfortunately, there isn't enough information on the page to give a conclusive answer.